# $X = \{0 ,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ be the metric space. How to define a continuous injective function from $X = \{0 ,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ to the cantor set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$X = \{0 ,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ be the metric space. Can anyone please tell me how to define a continuous injective function from $X = \{0 ,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ to the cantor set ?

Can anyone please give an idea ?

Comment: You can do better than that: you can define a homeomorphism from $X$ to the middle-thirds Cantor set $C$. Do you know that the points of $C$ are precisely the real numbers in $[0,1]$ that have ternary expansions $0.d_1d_2d_3\ldots_{\text{three}}$ that do not contain the digit $1$, so that $d_k\in\{0,2\}$ for $k=1,2,3,\ldots\;$?

Comment: What is the metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x\in X$, we have a sequence of zeros and ones.  Meanwhile the Cantor set is the set of all real numbers in the unit interval whose ternary expansion contains no $1$'s.  So the natural map would be to send a given sequence $x=(x_n)$ of zeros and ones to the number in the Cantor set whose ternary expression is $\sum a_n/3^n$, where $a_n=\begin{cases} 0 , x_n=0\\2, x_n=1\end{cases}$.

The map is automatically continuous because the $X$ is discrete.

It remains to prove injectivity.  But that's straight forward, because different sequences result in numbers with different ternary representations.

Answer (score 0):

The Cantor set is the intersection $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty C_n$$

where $C_0 = [0, 1]$ and $C_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}C_n \cup  \frac{2}{3}C_n$ for each $n\ge 0$. Every $C_n$ consists of $2^n$ disjoint parts of length $\frac{1}{3^n}$ each. (Shown by induction).

So if $(x_n)_{n=1}$ is a sequence of $0,1$'s we can use it to determine whether you take a left or a right turn at the next $C_n$, as it were. In the end we get an intersection of subintervals of the $C_n$, which is a decreasing intersection of sets of diameter $\frac{1}{3^n}$ so whose intersection is a unique point (by Cantor's intersection theorem). This then defines the image of the sequence.

Continuity is clear: when we have a small open interval around a point of intersection $y$, we can find $N$ so large that it contains a whole subinterval of that stage's $C_N$ that contains $y$ and then the product basic set that just fixes the first $N$ coordinates (so as to land in that subinterval) maps inside the open interval, showing continuity.

Think about it. It's usually presented as a ternary expansion map, or even as a formula like $$f((x_n)_n) = \sum_n \frac{1}{3^n}2x_n$$ etc. but the visual desciption is clearer to me. The Cantor set comes from the branches of a splitting tree and the $0,1$'s encode the path through that tree.